# NetBeans Maven {tomcat_base}/bin folder as false classpath

Tags: tomcat, maven, netbeans, classpath, web-deployment

I'm developing a Maven web app in NetBeans 7.1.1, with Apache Tomcat 7.0.22 as server. When running or debugging the app, the Java classes assume "/home/user/apache-tomcat-7.0.22/bin/" as the base for files.

For example, if creating a new file with "Writer rssFile = new FileWriter("test.xml");", this new file is created as "/home/user/apache-tomcat-7.0.22/bin/test.xml".

When searching for images or another files, the same problem occurs. It starts search in "/home/user/apache-tomcat-7.0.22/bin"...

The project files are not in Tomcat base, so I don know why bin folder is used as base for classpath... In code client-side (ex. *.jsp), the correct paths are found, but not in server-side code (Java classes)!

This problem is the same mentioned by other user in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774446/netbeans-setting-default-current-directory-for-tomcat , but none solutions were given.

This could be a bug with NetBeans Maven plugin? How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you're tied to using Tomcat then you can utilize two system properties:

- `catalina.home` - Where tomcat is installed (`/home/user/apache-tomcat-7.0.22`)
- `catalina.base` - Where a tomcat instance is based (typically the same as above, but can be configured to allow multiple Tomcat instances to be run all based from the same common binaries)

So you can use:

```
new File(System.getProperty("catalina.base") + "/conf/test.xml");
```

If you are trying to load resources that are bundled into your war there are some other things to you do to load resources with are container independent:

- If the resources are in the `WEB-INF/classes` folder, you can load them using as InputStreams using:

  > ```
  > Classloader.getResourceAsStream("/test.xml");
  > ```
- If you're using 2.5 servlet spec or beyond, and you have access to the ServletContext (or HttpServletRequest or HttpSession from which you can drill down to acquire the ServletContext):

  > ```
  > ServletContext.getRealPath("/"); // will return the root of your web app
  > ```